# Testing condition over a cell range and returning a value in excel

Tags: excel, formula

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

Assume that today's date is ***16-4-2018***. What I wanted was to get is a list of names of Users (***Column H***) separated by commas, who do not have PostIDs (***Column A***) with Status (***Column D***) either "***Analyzing***" OR "***Extended***" AND Validity date (***Column F***) in future i.e. greater than today's date ***16-4-2018***. Do not take into consideration the Time (***Column E***)

In the above screenshot the formula should return the following string:

**Sania, Rakesh**

because Shivalika, Kuldeep and Rahul all have status either Analyzing or Extended with a future Validity date.

I know I should have tried writing the formula myself but I don't have any idea which formula to use or where to start to achieve this result, so it would be a great help if someone could help me out on this :)

Comment: Take a [look](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) at [using](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/08/24/excel-sumproduct-function-formula-examples/) the `SUMPRODUCT` formula.

Comment: `VBA` would be best option for you.

Comment: I just checked what SUMPRODUCT is for and it seems like it's for multiplying arrays? Don't know how it will solve this problem tough

Comment: I was also thinking about VBA but to reduce complexity I was thinking if this problem could be solved just using formulas.